# how to build object with selected checkbox name or index

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to build object with index and layer2 which is existing inside  my code for multiple checkboxes because every time when I select check box, I want my object as following

```
objj{layer1:object, layer2:object}
```

if I have object, I can show my map and else I can remove my map if have index and layer name

```
$("#checkboxes").on('change', '[type=checkbox]', function () {
    console.log($(this).val());
    if (this.checked) {
        layer2 = new OM.layer.VectorLayer($(this).val(), {
            def: {
                type: OM.layer.VectorLayer.TYPE_PREDEFINED,
                dataSource: "tcg_seff",
                theme: $(this).val(),
                url: baseURL,
                loadOnDemand: false
            }
        });
        layersObjects.push($(this).val());
        alert("hellooo i am checked" + layersObjects);
        map.addLayer(layer2);
    } else {
        alert("hellooo i am unchecked" + layersObjects);
        map.removeLayer(layer2);
    }
});
```

Comment: Try `var obj = {};
$(':checked').each(function() {
    obj[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
});`

Comment: i want to include layer2 = new OM.layer.VectorLayer($(this).val(), {
            def: {
                type: OM.layer.VectorLayer.TYPE_PREDEFINED,
                dataSource: "tcg_seff",
                theme: $(this).val(),
                url: baseURL,
                loadOnDemand: false
            }
        });